# Is there any proper documentation for mod-evasive?

Tags: apache-2.2

`mod_evasive20` is one of the loaded modules on my httpd server. I read good things about how it can stop a DOS attack and wanted to try it out on my localhost. A search for mod_evasive turns up a [blog post](http://www.zdziarski.com/blog/?page_id=442) by the author which briefly describes what it does.

Other than that, I can't seem to find a reference or a documentation on the [apache modules site](https://modules.apache.org/search.php?query=true). I was wondering whether it is a module recognised by Apache since there is no mention of it on its website.

I have a `mod_evasive.conf` file sitting in the `/etc/http/conf.d` folder that contains the following lines:

```
LoadModule evasive20_module modules/mod_evasive20.so
<IfModule mod_evasive20.c>
 DOSHashTableSize    3097
 DOSPageCount        2
 DOSSiteCount        50
 DOSPageInterval     1
 DOSSiteInterval     1
 DOSBlockingPeriod   10
</IfModule>
```

My understanding from the setting is that if I were to click refresh or send a form more than two times in a one second interval, apache will issue a `403 error` and bar me from the site for 10 seconds. But that is not happening on my localhost. And I would like to know the reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Apache module site only lists modules provided with Apache official source code. Third party modules (like mod_evasive) are not listed there. The documentation for each third party module is usually done by their authors, and sometimes documentation is too brief or even lacking.

In the case of mod_evasive, maybe documentation is too brief because the module is really simple, the README file explains most important details, options have "useful" names and usually defaults are good for most people.

As for the reason you are not blocked when trying to trigger mod_evasive from localhost, maybe is the browser cache, a filter proxy or something else. You can try using wget (or curl, or similar) from the console:

```
while true ; do { wget --output-document=x.txt --no-proxy --no-cache http://localhost ; } ; done
```

(to stop, just Ctrl-C in the console)

Usually the output will be something like (getting 200 or 404 responses):

```
--2012-07-11 07:29:00--  http://localhost/
Resolving localhost... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
```

Then when mod_evasive triggers, you'll get 403 responses like:

```
--2012-07-11 07:29:00--  http://localhost/
Resolving localhost... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2012-07-11 07:29:00 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```